# Start Service with VBscript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am trying to have this script take a text file running and stopped services before a reboot and start any services that did not automatically start after the machine starts back up. The script that gets the list of service names, state and startmode and creates a comma separated text file line by line works fine. Here it is for reference (taken from the interwebs, lost the link in my travels. Modified slightly.):

```
Const ForAppending = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("service_list.txt", _ 
    ForWriting, True)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    objLogFile.Write objService.Name & "," 
    objLogFile.Write objService.StartMode & "," 
    objLogFile.Write objService.State 
    objLogFile.Writeline
Next

objLogFile.Close
```

This next bit reads the file line by line, compares the state of all of the services with the state of the services that were recorded before the machine was shut down. If they match, do nothing, if they are different, start the service:

```
Const ForReading = 1
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objServiceName = objWMIService.get("Win32_Service.Name='" & ServiceName & "'")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\some path\service_list.txt",ForReading,True,-2)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    fLine = Split(objFile.ReadLine,",")

    'wscript.echo fLine(2)
    if InStr(fLine(2),"Running") then
        'wscript.echo "it was running!"
        if objServiceName.Started then
            'do nothing
        else
            'Set servicetostart = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select " & ServiceName & " from Win32_Service Where Name ='Alerter'")
            'servicetostart.StartService()
            'Result = objServiceName.StartService
            'If 0 <> Result Then
            '   wscript.echo "Start " & ServiceName & " error:" & Result 
            'End If 
            objServiceName.StartService
            'wscript.echo Servicename & "could not start with error: " & Result
        end if
    end if
    'wscript.echo objServiceName
Loop
```

As of right now I am recieving an error whenever it actually tries to start the service. I receive a "Provider Failure code:80041004 Source:SWbemObjectEX". I have been looking through the posts about this error and attempting the fixes suggested. Also, as you can see, I have been trying variations, but I am afraid I am merely guessing.

So to my question, what is causing the "Provider Failure"? I have looked up these information for the Win32_Service Class here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods

and looked up the method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But have been unable to work out where the I am going wrong.

Thanks,

Joe

on a side note, the service I am testing, ie. making sure the service is starting, creating the text file, then stopping the service and running the "start service" code is Windows Defender. The service name is "WinDefend".

FINAL WORKING CODE:

```
Const ForReading = 1
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\Biffduncan\Monthly Server Maintanence\service_list.txt",ForReading,True,-2)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    fLine = Split(objFile.ReadLine,",")
    Set objService = objWMIService.get("Win32_Service.Name='" & fLine(0) & "'")

    if InStr(fLine(2),"Running") then
        'wscript.echo "it was running!"
        if objService.Started then
            'do nothing
        else
            Result = objService.StartService()
            if Result <> 0 then
                wscript.echo "The service: " & objService.Name & " did not start with error: " & Result
            else
                wscript.echo "Service " & objService.Name & " started"
            end if
        end if
    end if
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 0x80041004 means that the WMI provider encountered an error after it was already initialized. The error code doesn't say anything about the cause of the error, though, nor does it provide any details. Try running [`WBEMTest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx) or [`WMIDiag`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/03/wmidiag-2-1-is-here.aspx) to track down the error. Also check the eventlog for related errors/warnings. If everything else fails, try [rebuilding the WMI repository](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx).

As for your code, the first thing I'd do is strip it down to the bare minimum, to avoid potential error sources:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set svc = wmi.Get("Win32_Service.Name='WinDefend'")
rc = svc.StartService
WScript.Echo rc
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend writing the service status to a file at some random point in time, and then try starting services according to the contents of that file. There is no guarantee that the start mode hasn't been changed since the file was created, or that the service is even installed anymore.

Whether or not a service should be started is indicated by its `StartMode` property, so just check those services that are set to `Auto`. Services set to `Manual` will be started by the system on demand, so there's no need to launch them just because they were running when you took the snapshot.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartMode='Auto'"
For Each svc In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If Not svc.Started Then svc.StartService
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had attempted to start and stop the service yesterday using my own code `strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objService = objWMIService.get("Win32_Service.Name='WinDefend'")
 
objService.StartService`. My test yesterday worked, so I continued with the script. However I ran my code and yours, just now, and I got the same Provider Failure Error.

Comment: UPDATE - came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) document. If you look through the errors you will see the first range of error codes, 80041xx - 8004140 deal with improper permissions or a problems with the WMI infrastructure problem. Will continue updating when I find more info.

Comment: Yes, however you did not provide a reference, I just wanted to clarify. I did run WMIDiag, it came back with "WMIDiag detected issues that would cause WMI to not function properly." I am currently looking through the logs trying to find the cause.

Comment: This cause of the error is this line: Set objService = objWMIService.get("Win32_Service.Name='" & ServiceName & "'"). If I change the line to this: Set objService = objWMIService.get("Win32_Service.Name='WinDefend'") the script runs and starts whatever service I define, according to the text file.

Comment: It seems the variable `ServiceName` didn't have a value. I had assumed you added that line just for testing. What is its purpose when you read the services from a file anyway?

Comment: That was the conclusion I came to as well, I have a working script here, should I post it in the comments or add another post? My idea behind these two scripts was to take a snap shot of all the services and their states before a reboot. Then after the reboot have another script read the snap shot and modify the service states. So for example if there are some services that are set to "Manual" but were running before the reboot, record and start them.

Comment: Like I said: that isn't too useful. Services with start mode `Auto` will be started automatically after a reboot. If they don't, there usually is a problem that will prevent them from being started by your script as well, so you'll need to look into it anyway. Services with start mode `Manual` are meant to be started on demand. Just because they were running when you ran the script generating the list, doesn't mean they need to be running after a reboot.